# Как правильно передавать контекст в синглтон на android?

Tags: android, singleton

У меня есть несколько вопросов связанных с решением одной задачи. Суть довольно проста: в моем приложении я посылаю на сервер запросы и получаю от него ответы, и так получается что у меня иногда протухает токен который нужно сразу же обновлять. Метод обновления токенов находится почти в каждом активити в котором посылается запрос, и его копий насобиралось уже 10 штук. Так же у меня есть много других методов которые можно бы вынести в отдельный класс и при нужде из него тащить данные. В моем самом последнем вопросе мне добрые люди (**@ЮрийСПб спасибо**) посоветовали использовать синглтон для решения данной проблемы.

Погуглив некоторое время я понял что он был прав и синглтоны мне подойдут как нельзя лучше. Для этого я создал отдельный класс который будет вмещать все методы которые я хочу вынести. Во время дискуссии в комментариях мне посоветовали использовать синглтон Application и из него брать контекст. Если я правильно понял, то мне в синглтон нужно будет передавать контекст активити из которого я вызываю мой синглтон. Вроде как все понятно, но не очень. Вот у меня в моем синглтоне используется класс:

```
public synchronized static MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
                if (mInstance == null)
                    mInstance = new MySingleton();
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
```

который вроде как должен мне возвращать мой контекст но этого не происходит. Я хочу после обновления токенов записать в sharedpreferences мои новые токены, вот как выглядит моя функция обновления токенов в синглтоне:

```
private static void updateToken(String r_token) {
        APIService mAPIService = apiService(url);
        mAPIService.getNewToken(new ReqAccessToken(r_token)).enqueue(new Callback<ResNewTokens>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResNewTokens> call, @NonNull Response<ResNewTokens> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    acc_token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAccess_token();
                    ref_token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getRefresh_token(); // error

                    /*sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    editor.putString("access_token", acc_token);
                    editor.apply();
                    editor.putString("refresh_token", acc_token);
                    editor.apply();*/

                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("refresh_token_expired")) {
                            //logOut();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResNewTokens> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

и вот как выглядит весь мой класс синглтона:

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static String url;
    private static String ref_token;
    private static String acc_token;
    private static String appl_name, appl_lname, a_id;


    public synchronized static MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
                if (mInstance == null)
                    mInstance = new MySingleton();
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }


    private MySingleton() {
        Log.w("MY_TAG", "MySingleton");
    }

    public MySingleton(String url_l, String token_r, String token_a) {
        url = url_l;
        ref_token = token_r;
        acc_token = token_a;
    }

    public String getAcc_token() {
        return acc_token;
    }

    public void setAcc_token(String acc_token) {
        MySingleton.acc_token = acc_token;
    }

    public String getAppl_name() {
        return appl_name;
    }

    public String getAppl_lname() {
        return appl_lname;
    }

    public String getA_id() {
        return a_id;
    }

    private static void updateToken(String r_token) {
        APIService mAPIService = apiService(url);
        mAPIService.getNewToken(new ReqAccessToken(r_token)).enqueue(new Callback<ResNewTokens>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResNewTokens> call, @NonNull Response<ResNewTokens> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    acc_token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAccess_token();
                    ref_token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getRefresh_token(); // error

                    /*sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    editor.putString("access_token", acc_token);
                    editor.apply();
                    editor.putString("refresh_token", acc_token);
                    editor.apply();*/

                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("refresh_token_expired")) {
                            //logOut();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResNewTokens> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    public static void getPersonalData() {
        final APIService mAPIService = apiService(url);
        mAPIService.getData("Bearer " + acc_token).enqueue(new Callback<UserInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<UserInfo> call, @NonNull Response<UserInfo> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    appl_name = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getApp_f_name();
                    appl_lname = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getApp_l_name();
                    a_id = String.valueOf(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getApp_id());

                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("access_token_expired")) {
                            updateToken(ref_token);
                            getPersonalData();

                        }
                        if (errorBody.string().contains("invalid_token")) {
                            getPersonalData();
                        }
                        if (errorBody.string().contains("refresh_token_expired")) {
                            //logOut();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<UserInfo> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    /*private void logOut() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPreferences.edit().remove("access_token").apply();
        sharedPreferences.edit().remove("refresh_token").apply();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", false).apply();

        Intent intent = new Intent(mInstance, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }*/


    public static APIService apiService(String url) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

вероятнее всего в процессе создания моего синглтона у меня возникли ошибки но я не могу понять где именно. Вот например как из активити я создаю мой синглтон:

```
ms = new MySingleton(url, refresh_token, access_token);
MySingleton.getPersonalData();
```

вроде у меня получилось обновить из него мои токены, но дальше этого я не смог продвинутся. Не могу понять где и что я не так сделал.

Comment: Какой-же он у Вас синглтон, если у него паблик конструктор и Вы создаёте через него сколь угодно экземпляров. `Singleton.getInstance()` должен быть единственным способом получения его единственного экземпляра.

Comment: а как же мне тогда получить из настроек данные? я в конструктор передаю переменные полученные из sharedpreferences, либо нужно как-то передавать что-то для получения доступа в настройкам

Comment: Ну а геттеры/сеттеры у Вас для чего? Только зачем опять поля статические? Без `static` не может обойтись только `mInstance`.

Comment: теперь не очень понял) вот например у меня есть только один конструктор в моем недосинглтоне Singleton.getInstance() и дальше мне нужно как-то передавать и получать данные из этого синглтона, и желательно это делать в пределах синглтона, а не привязываться к определенной активити

Comment: `MySingleton.getInstance().get/set<Что-то>`

Comment: это писать в активити нужно? я просто думал что можно как-то вызвать sharedpreference manager чтобы из него писать что-то, или это нельзя сделать? или я может просто не очень понятно объясняю что пытаюсь сделать :)